# im new to angularjs , ng-if was not working. order1 value is im giving externally

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<tr ng-repeat=" x in list " ><div ng-if ="order1 == x.orderNo">
    <td>{{x.ShippingLine}}</td>
    <td>{{x.orderNo}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Buyer}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Items}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{x.shipTo}}</td>
    <td>{{x.CapitalItem}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Status}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Type}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Comments}}</td>{{x.orderNo}}</tr></div>
    {{x.orderNo}}
 </table>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a better question and a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div>` tag starts inside the `<tr>` and ends outside of the `</tr>`

Further more please note that even if the <`div>` was correcly placed, you would get an empty `tr`

You most likely need to put the ng-if on the `tr` instead.

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30kyw5u7/)